# What do you call someone who puts a hit out on someone?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for someone who hires a hitman or assassin?

Comment: Contractor? Source: playing the Hitman video games

Comment: @CalebBernard - In general, though, a *contractor* is the person who contracts to perform a service: in this case, the hitman himself.  I haven't played the video game - perhaps they have it the other way around - but in that case I would say they'd got it wrong.

Comment: @MT_Head maybe, or maybe I've misremembered the game... Either way, I think you're right. The contractor should refer to the hitman himself.

Answer (score 1):

In cases of contract killing, you have the **employer**, **the hitman** and **the victim**

The person who hires the hitman is **the employer**.

> - employ (verb) -  to use or get the services of (someone) to do a particular job. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/employ)

Comment: Pity it's so generic, though.  Also - from the point of view of the hitman, s/he could also be called the "client" or the "customer".  (Both of which are just as generic, I know.)